# Ubuntu 21.10 switched to nftables, so why is iptables still available?

Tags: iptables, ufw, 21.10, nftables

According to [21.10 release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951):

> nftables is now the default backend for the firewall.

However, having installed Ubuntu 21.10, I can see I still have iptables (and ufw) installed by default:

```
m@m-VirtualBox:~$ whereis iptables

iptables: /usr/sbin/iptables /usr/share/iptables /usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz

m@m-VirtualBox:~$ whereis ufw

ufw: /usr/sbin/ufw /usr/lib/ufw /etc/ufw /usr/share/ufw /usr/share/man/man8/ufw.8.gz
```

Why does this happen?

As far as I'm aware, `ufw` is a wrapper around iptables, not nftables.

Can I safely use these commands? Or should I take care to never type `iptables` or `ufw` in the terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After your `whereis iptables` command, you should follow the files. Example, from a 20.04 server:

```
doug@s19:~$ whereis iptables
iptables: /usr/sbin/iptables /usr/share/iptables /usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /usr/sbin/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 23  2020 /usr/sbin/iptables -> /etc/alternatives/iptables
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 18  2021 /etc/alternatives/iptables -> /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Feb 28  2020 /usr/sbin/iptables-nft -> xtables-nft-multi
doug@s19:~$ ls -l /usr/sbin/xtables-nft-multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 220488 Feb 28  2020 /usr/sbin/xtables-nft-multi
```

So, iptables is actually using nftables.

nftables can interpret iptables syntax.

Comment: `readlink -f` is your friend here: `readlink -f $(which iptables) -> /usr/sbin/xtables-nft-multi`

Comment: `nftables can interpret iptables syntax.` is not _really_ true and should apparently not be used together. See [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/08/18/iptables-the-two-variants-and-their-relationship-with-nftables#).

Answer (score 6):

I don't have all the answers to your questions but I do have some of them.

UFW is a firewall abstraction layer that can use either iptables **or** nftables as the back-end firewall.  It's just Ubuntu's handy helper, much like Firewalld + firewall-cmd are for Red Hat variants.

A fresh server installation of Ubuntu 21.10 Server shows exactly what you are seeing - that in fact the back-end is still using iptables on a standard server installation.

xtables-nft-multi (or simply xtables-multi)'s manpage shows an explanation:

> xtables-nft  are versions of iptables that use the nftables API.  This is a set of tools to help the system administrator migrate
> the ruleset from iptables(8), ip6tables(8), arptables(8), and ebtables(8) to nftables(8).

So far as I can tell, you are correct that while Ubuntu seems to be moving toward nftables as a replacement for iptables, they aren't there yet.

The nice thing though, is that if you've been using UFW all this time, nothing will change from a management perspective since both iptables and nftables seem to be interchangeable, since nft will accept iptables syntax, even if you have funky rules in /etc/ufw/before.rules for example.